# Spark - Loops lead to "GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I have written a Spark program which accesses several cached tables using loops.

For some time the code is executed quite fast, but at some point stops progressing. When looking at the Spark GUI i get an "GC overhead limit exceeded".

The code basically looks like this (it shall simply illustrate the structure of the code and problem, but looks different in fact):

```
val table1 = sqlc.read.load(...)
val table2 = sqlc.read.load(...)
val table3 = sqlc.read.load(...)

table1.registerTempTable("table1")
table2.registerTempTable("table2")
table3.registerTempTable("table3")

sqlc.cacheTable("table1")
sqlc.cacheTable("table2")
sqlc.cacheTable("table3")

val result = someArray.foldLeft(0.0) {
  (someAcc, someParam) => {
      someAcc + anotherArray.foldLeft(0.0){
         (anotherAcc, anotherParam) => {
            val val1 = sqlc.sql(SELECT ... FROM table1 ...).first().getDouble(0)
            val val2 = sqlc.sql(SELECT ... FROM table2 ...).first().getDouble(0)
            val val3 = sqlc.sql(SELECT ... FROM table3 ...).first().getDouble(0)
            anotherAcc + val3
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what i am doing wrong?

Btw.: The spark driver has 90G of RAM and this program is executed in a fresh Spark context created by Zeppelin. Also as far as I can see, it is hardly possible to solve this calculation using pure sql and joins.

Comment: How much memory you configured for the spark worker? btw, I feel the code might not very efficient.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Rockie. I just solved the problem. It was related to a wrong setting of the driver memory. After fixing this, the job ran like a charm. Apart from that, you are right: if possible, it should be avoided to run so much work of the job on the driver and not the workers. The worker memory was not an issue tho.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. I thought driver memory was an issue unless your someArray and anotherArray are large. Seems I was wrong.